# Spring Boot Foreign key returns null

Tags: spring-boot

I'm working on an application that can send the User's location to the database .I have two tables Users and Locations , what I want to do is make column 'email' from Users foreign key to the Location table so I did this in the Location class:

```
  @ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user",referencedColumnName = "email")
private User user;
```

In the class LocationServiceImplementation i did a 'create' method:

```
 @Override
public Location create(LocationCreateDTO locationCreateDTO) throws BusinessException {
    final User currentUser = ((CustomUserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUser();
    Location location =new Location();
    location.setDate(new Date());
    location.setLatitude(locationCreateDTO.getLatitude());
    location.setLongitude(locationCreateDTO.getLongitude());
    location.setUser(currentUser);
    final Location locationCreated=locationRepository.save(location);

    return locationCreated;
}
```

The problem is that it says the user is null in the method setUser

```
 public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user.setEmail(user.getEmail());
}
```

[The Users table looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vIcd.png)
[The Locations table looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZsu0.png)

[This is the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VITMl.png)

Answer (score 1):

I added in the void setUser this line and seems to be working:
this.user=user;